# ActionBar-PullToRefresh nothing happens

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, pull-to-refresh

I'm trying to add `ActionBar-PushToRefresh` to my project. I've followed the instructions from Chris Banes Github there: [Github ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh)

Here is my view from which I want to enable the `PullToRefresh` feature:

```
     <uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/ptr_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <!-- Your content, here we're using a ScrollView -->
     <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
      android:text="PULLTOREFRESH THE VIEW"
      android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </ScrollView>

 </uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout>
```

**And here is my Activity to display the view:**

```
 package com.Test.pulltorefresh;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.ActionBarPullToRefresh;
 import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.Options;
 import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout;


 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private PullToRefreshLayout mPullToRefreshLayout;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Now find the PullToRefreshLayout to setup
    mPullToRefreshLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.ptr_layout);

    // Now setup the PullToRefreshLayout
    ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(this)
            // Mark All Children as pullable
            .allChildrenArePullable()
                    // Set the OnRefreshListener
            //.listener(this)
                    // Finally commit the setup to our PullToRefreshLayout
            .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);
 }
}
```

When I launch my app, I got the blank view but nothing happens when I'm trying to `PushToRefresh` my view. Can someone show me how to fix it, I know that I've missed something. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit partial but...
[you could consider using this](https://github.com/JoeDailey/Android-Simple-Pull-to-Refresh)

Comment: But I still want to use ActionBar-PullToRefresh for a good start, can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have already achieved the functionality, but in the code above, you have commented out the line which defines the action on pulling the view.

```
//.listener(this)
```

You should uncomment this line and define the listener method, which should be called when the view is pulled.